# Python stuck while executing SQL update query

Tags: python, sql

My python script is stuck on cursor execution and I have problem to find out why.

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@user')
cursor = db.cursor()

for i in range(1, 10):
    insert_data = """
    update products set prd_stock_holder = '~',prd_prod_quality = 'FREE' 
    where PRD_PRI_ID = (select prd_pri_id from products join PRODUCT_INFOS
        on prd_pri_id = pri_id
            where PRI_code = '%s')""" %i

    cursor.execute(insert_data) # stuck here

    print "product %s updated" %i # never printed

db.commit()
```

Comment: How big are your tables? Might be long processing time. How does it work in sql*plus or your Oracle client? Try committing after each `execute` (i.e., indent `db.commit` in loop).

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular issue with insert to a MySQL Database.
Moving the db.commit() inside the loop solved my issue.

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@user')
cursor = db.cursor()

for i in range(1, 10):
    insert_data = """
    update products set prd_stock_holder = '~',prd_prod_quality = 'FREE' 
    where PRD_PRI_ID = (select prd_pri_id from products join PRODUCT_INFOS
        on prd_pri_id = pri_id
            where PRI_code = '%s')""" %i

    cursor.execute(insert_data) # stuck here
    db.commit()
    print "product %s updated" %i # never printed
```

Comment: Ok but semantics changes: if your loop fails, you end up having a partial commit, which is not possible in the original snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

A cause may be a lock on the Oracle RDBMS. You may try checking if your session is locked waiting for a resource (e.g. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tracking_oracle_blocking_sessions.htm).

Please keep in mind that locks may be connected to the execution plan the db has decided to apply. By rewriting your update query you might benefit from thinner lock acquisition.

Comment: Indeed, according to the instruction from your link, my session is locked. So do you think the query itself in that form cause that issue?

Comment: It would be useful to have the execution plan.  For instance, you might discover that fetching all the tuples `(id, stuff_you_need_to_generate_update_value... )` and then batch update by id may be more selective in terms of locking.

Comment: thank You very much, splitting select and update into different queries helped out